# fix dropdownlist control's list position

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am facing an issue with the dropdownlist which is binded in code behind file but my issue is related to UI.

```
<div id="Div2" runat="server" class="dropdownstate" style="margin-left: 10px;">
                        <asp:DropDownList Width="200px" ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" Font-Names="Segoe UI"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList4_SelectedIndexChanged"  AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
```

the snapshot given below:

[image]

The option list in dropdownlist is not actually dropping down..it is going upwards.
and the issue is with th IE only.
In chrome and FF its working completely alright.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give URL of this site? i think its IE-9 right?

Comment: It seems IE9, please check once changing Document-Mode in lower version.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma..I tried but no change.